RSTP Inferior BPDU receive on Alternate Port
As per the specification and the materials available online, RSTP is supposed to have the features like Uplink fast and Backbone fast already defined in the IEEE specification. I did have a look but I don't see where exactly in the state machines the BackBoneFast effective code is there, it sure processes the inferior BPDU but it doesn't even make a record of it from the message to port priority vectors.
If anyone has any idea please let me know
Accepts Inferior BPDUs (CISCO)

You can download the original IEEE 802.1Q standard here: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/browse/standards/get-program/page/series?id=68 (free after registration).

yep, i have read the specification and i don't see how it implements the BackBoneFast feature in the spec., the only thing it does when received a inferior bpdu from the designated bridge is signal disputed, it doesn't even record the message for port role comparision
